# how to use mkdosfs command to do partition of 200MB with FAT32

Tags: 14.04, sd-card, fdisk

I want to do two partitions for my SD card with *FAT* and *EXT4* using *Ubuntu*.

For this, I found two commands:

```
mkdosfs /dev/sda1 -n 
mke2fs /dev/sda1 -L
```

But how should I specify the size, for *FAT* I need *200MB* and rest with *EXT4*.

When tried to give `mkdosfs /dev/sda1 -n` I got an error.

```
sudo mkdosfs /dev/sda
mkfs.fat 3.0.28 (2015-05-16)
mkdosfs: unable to open /dev/sda: Device or resource busy
```

Comment: When I see `/dev/sda1` I'm thinking that you try to edit a partition on the drive, that your system is booted from. You should boot from one drive and edit partitions on another drive. If you boot from a live USB drive with Ubuntu, you can use `gparted`, which has a graphical user interface. It is quite easy to use in order to edit partitions and create file systems.

Comment: I cross checked and its my sdcard only, even the size is showing correctly

Comment: So your Ubuntu system is booted from another drive. Fine :-)  `gparted` is already there in Ubuntu live, but in an installed system, you must install it, `sudo apt install gparted`. You must also unmount all partitions on the SD card before you start editing the partitions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions) You must create partitions first, then you can create a filesystem in them. Or you can do it all in Gparted. If you want specific help for your situation, please [edit] your question to include the output of the `lsblk` command.

Comment: Iam using VM and gparted is throwing error

Comment: _What_ error? Please [edit] your question with specific information (e.g. screenshot of GParted and/or the `lsblk` output I requested earlier).